# Unable to retrieve any posts of CPT in wp-admin

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, wp-admin

I have a site with a few custom post types. Those are all registered in a very similar fashion sharing most attributes:

```
const ARGS = [
    'hierarchical'          => true,
    //'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    //'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'page',
    'show_in_rest'          => false,
];
```

For example the CPTs `order` and `person` are registered like this

```
private static function register_order()
{
    $args = array_merge(
        [
            'label'                 => __( 'order', 'X' ),
            'labels'                => [...],
            'supports'              => ['title', 'editor', 'author'],
        ],
        self::ARGS
     );

    register_post_type( 'order', $args );
}

private static function register_person()
{
    $args = array_merge(
        [
            'label'                 => __( 'person', 'X' ),
            'labels'                => [...],
            'supports'              => ['title', 'author'],
        ],
        self::ARGS
    );

    register_post_type( 'person', $args );
}
```

However, when in the wp-admin, I currently only see `person`s whereas `order`s gets me an empty list.

[image]

Debugging this with the Debug Bar and Query Monitor, I get the following main query for `order` (redacted the `post_status` for both queries)

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_parent
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND (wp_posts.ID = '0')
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'order'
AND (...) 
ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC, wp_posts.post_title ASC
```

And the query for `person` is

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_parent
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'person'
AND (...) 
ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC, wp_posts.post_title ASC
```

---

Now I understand SQL good enough to know that this line

```
AND (wp_posts.ID = '0')
```

is the reason I don't get any results. I just don't have any idea why it is there. I don't have any `pre_get_posts` hook set, deactivated all plugins except this one, no change whatsoever.

Comment: Are you using `pre_get_posts`? Note that filter is for all queries, not just frontend queries, you have to check for the main query, and you have to explicitly check for admin vs frontend, or it'll also be applied to all your admin post screens

Comment: @TomJNowell No. The installation is yet very basic: ACF (which I disabled, nothing changed) and my custom plugin. Which right now only adds the CPTs and REST endpoints (the latter I disabled, nothing changed)

Comment: `order` is in the list of CPT that you cannot use : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: @mmm Thanks alot! Please write it up as an answer. Why does the [new docu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) not show vital info such as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mmm](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/74311/mmm) pointed out [in the comments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307090/unable-to-retrieve-any-posts-of-cpt-in-wp-admin#comment453178_307090), `order` should not be used as a name for a custom post type, as it may "interfere with other WordPress functions". Read more in the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Reserved_Post_Types):

> ## Reserved Post Types The following post types are reserved and used by WordPress already.
>
> - `post`
> - `page`
> - `attachment`
> - `revision`
> - `nav_menu_item`
> - `custom_css`
> - `customize_changeset`
>
> In addition, the following post types should not be used as they
>   interfere with other WordPress functions.
>
> - `action`
> - `author`
> - `order`
> - `theme`